# How can pove a generalization of Brahmagupta theorem

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

In the figure:[image]

If $\frac{MQ}{BA}=\frac{NP}{BC}$ and $\angle MBA = \angle CBN=\frac{\pi}{2}$
And $D, E$ be the midpoint of $MN, PQ$ respectively, then show that $DE \perp AC$
If $P=Q=B$ this is a generalization of Brahmagupta theorem (Figure 2)
[image]

If $P=Q=B$ and $M, B, C$ are colliear, and $N, B, A$ are collinear; This case is [Brahamagupta theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\vec{BA}=\vec{a}$, $\vec{BC}=\vec{c}$, $\vec{QM}=\vec{m}$ and $\vec{PN}=\vec{n}$.

Thus, $$\vec{ED}=\frac{1}{2}(\vec{m}+\vec{n})$$ and we need to prove that
$$(\vec{c}-\vec{a})(\vec{m}+\vec{n})=0$$ or
$$\vec{c}\vec{m}=\vec{a}\vec{n},$$ which is obvious because
$$\frac{|\vec{m}|}{|\vec{a}|}=\frac{MQ}{BA}=\frac{NP}{BC}=\frac{|\vec{n}|}{|\vec{c}|}$$ and
$$\measuredangle MBC=\measuredangle NBA.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

I have a generalization of the Brahmagupta theorem, but I did not go into the proof process. Definitely valid:

From point $K$ outside a circle $C_1$ we draw the lines $KB$ and $KD$ so that they are perpendicular to each other and intersect the circle $C_1$ at points $A, B, C, D$. The construction is possible only if the distance of $K$ from the center of the circle $C_1$ is less than $R \sqrt {2}$, where $R$ is the radius of the circle $C_1$. Prove that if the line $KM$ is perpendicular to $AD$, then $MB = MC = MK$ will hold.[image]

Comment: You have effectively observed that [Brahmagupta's thm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta_theorem) applies to *self-intersecting* orthodiagonal cyclic quad $ABCD$. (This gives congruence of $BM$ & $CM$. Further congruence with $KM$ is a follow-on property of right $\triangle KBC$, which also holds in the original thm.) This situation isn't noted explicitly in the Wikipedia article (or its references), so it's nice to see. However, a sufficiently-flexible proof of Brahmagupta (say, with coordinates) naturally subsumes this case, so your observation, while insightful, likely isn't "new".

Comment: In any case, your result doesn't serve as an answer to the question and shouldn't be posted as one. If you seek proof, you should post your own question separately. Cheers!